# TCL - set multiple variables to 0

Tags: tcl, var

I have many counts variable (ie: count1 count2 count3....)

```
set count1 0
set count2 0
set count3 0
```

Instead of typing all on separate lines, is there a shorter way in TCL to just set all the count1.....count100 0

ie: set count1 [list ....]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have this many variables close related enough, I'd suggest using an array instead, and you can use a loop with it:

```
for {set i 0} {$i <= 100} {incr i} {
    set count($i) 0
}
```

That way if you don't need the counts, you can always unset the array and free up some memory pretty easily and quickly.

If for some reason you cannot use an array instead of a normal variable, then you can still do it like this:

```
for {set i 0} {$i <= 100} {incr i} {
    set count$i 0
}
```

If the variables are not too much related to each other and there aren't that many of them, you can use `lassign` and [`lrepeat`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrepeat.htm) like this:

```
lassign [lrepeat 4 0] a b c d
```

In the above, `lrepeat` will create a list containing the element `0` 4 times.

Comment: If you're using “compact” numeric indices, as in a classic C or Fortran array, use a `list`. Much faster for that job.

Answer (score 2):

> I have many counts variable (ie: count1 count2 count3....)

Don't, simply maintain a single Tcl list and access the various counts by their list position:

```
set count [list 0 0 0 0]; # This is your "multi-set"

lindex $count 0; # a.k.a. $count0 or [set count0]
lset count 0 5; # a.k.a. [set count0 5]

lindex $count 1; # a.k.a. $count1
lset count 1 10; # a.k.a. [set count1 10]
```

If you still want to "explode" the list encoding of your counts into a collection of dedicated variables, this is a generalised variant of Jerry's suggestion using `lassign` then:

```
% set varNames [lmap idx [lsearch -all $count *] {string cat count $idx}]
count0 count1 count2 count3
% lassign $count {*}$varNames
% info vars count*
count count0 count1 count2 count3
```

Comment: Better use a single scripted for-loop to define the variables when starting from the list, rather than lmap/ lassign.

Answer (score 2):

The `set` command returns the value that was loaded into the variable. So when initializing just a few variables to 0, you can do:

```
set count1 [set count2 [set count3 0]]
```

But with 100 variables that is not practical.

If you have 100 counters it is almost certainly much easier to use an array. Counter sounds like you will be using the `incr` command on the variables to count something. Since Tcl 8.5, variables (including array elements) don't need to be initialized to 0 for `incr` to work. You can just use `incr count($x)` without any prior initialization.